# Firebase Email sign-in not working with custom domains

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to implement passwordless email sign-in into my flutter app and i'm running into an issue.

I have a custom domain linked to my firebase project `link.myapp.app`. Dynamic links are enabled for this domain (i have a URL prefix : `https://link.myapp.app/`). This domain is also authorized in my authentication whitelist.

I send the sign-in email from my client specifying this domain like so:

```dart
      await _firebaseAuth.sendSignInLinkToEmail(
          email: email,
          actionCodeSettings: new ActionCodeSettings(
            dynamicLinkDomain: "link.myapp.app",
            url: "https://link.myapp.app/",
            handleCodeInApp: true,
            androidPackageName: packageInfo.packageName,
            androidMinimumVersion: "21",
            androidInstallApp: true,
            iOSBundleId: packageInfo.packageName,
          ));
```

But when i click on the link received by email I get the following error:

```
Invalid Dynamic Link
Requested URL (https://link.myapp.app/?apiKey=AIzeSyBu7iTkumJxSYX8ioM3--6FgBbpeoJIbZI&oobCode=D-cYxG2g_sOjoxjawS-rkZR46vjbj9e7hfJUnYYP-jYAAAF4X9TtJQ&mode=signIn&lang=en&_imcp=1) must be a parsable and complete DynamicLink.

If you are the developer of this app, ensure that your Dynamic Links domain is correctly configured and that the path component of this URL is valid.
```

Comment: it says the dynamic link is invalid, not that the domain is invalid.  Try using the URL builder and seeing if that works better? Also try adding &d=1 to the dynamic link and correcting any errors shown in the debug output.

Comment: @Kato what do you mean by URL builder ? And if if navigate to `https://link.myapp.app?d=1` I get the same Invalid Dynamic Link error. This makes me think, what is the difference between a URL prefix and a dynamic link in dynamic link

Comment: Pretty sure "path component of this URL is valid" is referring to the value of `url` here where you are using the dynamic links domain to forward users to the same dynamic links domain causing an infinite loop. `url` should point somewhere else like `https://myapp.app/signin`.

Answer (score 0):

As per firebase "specify the URL patterns allowed in your deep link and fallback links using regular expressions. By allowing redirects to only allowlisted URLs, you prevent phishing."

There is an issue in Regex URL pattern that you have added in allowlist URL pattern. To confirm the issue follow below steps :

1. Delete all the patterns and again test the firebase dynamic link. If it work it means you need to correct your regex url .
2. Follow the syntax [guide](https://github.com/google/re2/wiki/Syntax) to add regex url and test again.

[image: URL pattern]
[image: regex url]

Comment: Thanks for the reply, unfortunately I dont have any URL pattern in my Allowlist specified. I was planning on doing that after it worked without actually. I contacted firebase support but the've been really unhelpful sor far :/

Comment: @ThéoChampion, you might have solved the issue so far, if so, could you share how? if not, Try to reformat your redirect link to `For example: https://example.com/acctmgmt/__/auth/action?mode=<action>&oobCode=<code>.` based on https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/7000714?authuser=0&hl=en#actionlink.